# Como execultar arquivo .sh em button

Tags: php, html, linux

É possivel executar um arquivo que `.sh` em um `button` , exemplo:  `/bin/importa.sh`

em um `<a href""></a>` também serve.

Comment: Alguma das respostas ajudou a resolver o problema?

Comment: Testado e validado, Obrigado !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Diretamente pelo HTML não, com PHP é possível fazer isso de algumas formas, uma opção é a função [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shell-exec.php) (não muito diferente de `system` ou `exec`):

```
<form method="post">
  <button type="submit" name="button">Importar</button>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['button'])) {
    shell_exec("/bin/importa.sh");
}

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Se estiver liberado em seu servidor, use `system()`

Exemplo:

```
$comando = "./bin/importa.sh";
$parametros = $_POST['parametros'];
system($comando $parametros,$retorno);
```

Recebendo `$parametros` para passar ao arquivo dados para execução, ele usa a função para realizar a execução do bash

Para maiores informações: [Veja a página da função no site do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.system.php)

Answer (score 4):

Pelo HTML não, você tem que fazer uma chamada para uma página PHP e executar o trecho de código.

```
exec("/bin/importa.sh", $output);
```

verifique se você tem as permissões necessárias para executar esse arquivo.